# How to bind Knockout.js to existing table grid?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm a newbie to Knockout.js. I implemented the Knockout.js by loading data from ajax source and use foreach loop to create a table of the data. The tutorial i followed is here

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=933

My issue here is, due to the nature of my application, I find that the first load is better served from the server side using a grid component and I only want Knockout.js to take care of "Add" row, "Update" a row and "delete" a row.

My question is,

1) how do I replace the "first" load and populate the lookupCollection :ko.observableArray() in the article with the default data in the html table?
2) Related to #1. If the first load, the table layout with data is constructed from the server side, then how do I bind "foreach" to the grid so "add" can be performed on lookupCollection?

Thanks and again, I'm a newbie, I must be missing some key concepts here.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to pass your initial data into your view model.  Since you are using asp.net it would look something like this:

```
//Dump raw data into javascript variable
var data = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Data);

function ViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    //Unpack raw data
    self.lookupCollection = ko.observableArray(data.lookupCollection);
}

//initialize view model
var viewModel = new ViewModel(data);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Hey Bradley. Thanks for the suggestion. Okay. That answer the first questions. In that case, what about my 2nd issue? Meaning, the grid needs to be rendered on the server side on first load. How do I structure the table layout using data-bind foreach?

Comment: That should not change: <tbody data-bind="foreach: lookupCollection">